# AngularJS is undefined in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, angularjs

I'm working on a massive application that uses AngularJs.

When I view the page in IE8 I get super nifty console errors like `Object doesn't support property or method 'module'`, `Object doesn't support property or method 'widget'`, `unable to get value of the property 'controller': object is null or undefined`, and `IE really sucks, cant you just tell them to download chrome?`

After fighting with it for a while I decided to log the `typeof angular`, to which the console returned `undefined`.

Everything works as expected in IE9, IE10, and all browsers that don't suck.

Please help!

**Edit**:

It appears that angular is `undefined` before it gets to my first controller, so I don't think it has to do with the ieshim ...

Comment: Super nifty? Never thought of describing it that way... :)

Comment: Have you been over http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie ?

Comment: jbabey: yeah, I've also implemented the angular-ui ieshiv.js after following that guide failed to solve my problem.

Comment: Did you check the document mode?
See [http://stackoverflow.com/a/33936714/483647](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33936714/483647)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was totally my bad (or the guy that started this app months ago).

My application controller had `var angular = angular || {}` at the top, IE8 didn't agree with this declaration.

After removing that all is well.

Answer (score 5):

I've been working with IE8 for six months now, feel your pain.

Without seeing your code it's hard exactly to say what's wrong

Here's a very very basic page I just tested with IE8, for you to compare against:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prompt Detail View</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- disable browser cache -->
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />


    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script>
        document.createElement('ng-include');
        document.createElement('ng-pluralize');
        document.createElement('ng-view');
        // Optionally these for CSS
        document.createElement('ng:include');
        document.createElement('ng:pluralize');
        document.createElement('ng:view');
    </script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-1.0.2.js" ng:autobind></script>


<script>
var pageModule = angular.module('pageModule',[])
.controller('pageCtrl',function($scope) {
   $scope.foo = 'my foo'; 
});

</script>
</head>


<body>
    <div ng-app="pageModule"
        ng-controller="pageCtrl">
            {{foo}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I see a couple things here that i'm missing, i'll blindly add them in hopes for progress!

Comment: Yes, it works. But don't forget, that old browsers support only old versions of Angular. I use 1.2.4 with IE8 =)

Comment: I'd like to point out that I've never been comfortable inventing tags for the purposes of use with angular. It's non-semantic and non-standard. When angular provides ways to do it via data attributes, why would you consider going that route? In my opinion using your own (and angular-native) custom tags is akin to using flash.

Comment: @dudewad- agreed. The purpose of my above posting was for basic debugging and sanity check

Comment: @Saike Thanks... Your comment saved me... Spent more than couple of hours to find the broken place in angular. finally fixed by version change.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue, my IE9 browser didn't recognize any AngularJs tag, after trying everything I decided to run the html file in a server and it worked.

To summerize, when I executed the file as follows it didn't work

file:///C:/AngularJS/firstTest.html

when I executed the file in the server as follows it did work

http://localhost:7001/AngularJS/firstTest.html

Comment: I know that if you want to use some modules (like ngResource) you have to have an active server.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var versionError = angular.module('versionErrors', [])
  .controller('versionCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Shantha Moorthy K';
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS with Lower version Error's</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>


<body>
  <div ng-app="versionErrors" ng-controller="versionCtrl">
    {{name}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### Object doesn't support property or method 'module'

`If you are using AngularJS + Lower version of IE(8), Please include the content="IE=edge".

After include that you will overcome the below error's.

1. Object expected
2. Object doesn't support property or method 'module'` ##